# Why the MSE of the fitted data is not equal to the sum of the bias and the variance in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, variance, decomposition, mean-square-error

I use simple linear regression and I want to find the decomposition of MSE, that is as a sum of the bias, the variance and the variance of the error term. I have the following code:

```
n <- 100
Sigma <- 2
x <- rnorm(n, 0, 3)
y <- x + rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(Sigma))

sim_data <- data.frame(y,x)

model <- lm(y ~ x, data = sim_data)
mse1 <- mean(summary(model)$residuals^2)

fitted <- predict(model,data.frame(x))
mse2 <- mean((fitted-y)^2)

# decomposition of MSE into bias, variance and variance of error
mse3 <- mean((x-mean(fitted))^2) + var(fitted) + Sigma
```

`mse1` and `mse2` are equal, but `mse3` is not the correct MSE. What am I doing wrong in the decomposition of MSE into bias, variance and variance of the error terms?

Comment: Note that you are comparing different stuff. You are looking at mse of residuals, ms1 and mse2 -- which you have computed incorrectly btw, and comparing that to ms3 which contains variance of fitted values and not of residuals .. So yes the two values above will be completely different.

Comment: @Onyambu why mse1 and mse2 are wrong? both are the mse of the linear model. In ms3 I want to make the decomposition of mse1 into bias, variance and variance of error terms. So what do I have to correct?

Comment: the correct mse is `sigma(model)^2` which is `deviance(model)/(n-2)` also `var(model$residuals)*(n-1)/(n-2)` all these are different from ms1and ms2 given above. You have `mean(model$residuals^2)` this is incorrect. Mean divides by `n` not taking into consideration the df. thus you could do `mean(model$residuals^2)*n/(n-2)`

Comment: Also note that the parameters are unbiased thus the results would be the variance iof the residuals + 0

Comment: @Onyambu so how to obtain the decomposition of MSE based on what you say?

Comment: Simple, just sum the bias and variance.. ie `mean(model$residuals)^2 + var(model$residuals)*(n-1)/(n-2)`. is the mse. the first part is 0

Comment: @Onyambu ok, the first part is 0, but why? I mean that based on theory, in the decomposition of MSE, we have the squared of the bias. But this is not appeared on what you said. Also, based on theory, the variance of the errors is included in the decomposition of MSE, but you do not include it.

Comment: I just gave you a formula where I did Bias^2 + Var. Its linear model. we expect the bias to be 0. and that is exactly what happens here. Then check the variance. Note that this is the MSE of the residuals, you could do mse of parameters too and still you will end up with the same results. Just study the theory, seems you are stuck abit on how to decompose mse.